# How to use Javascript to populate a select form (i.e. dropdown) based on elements in a class

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

I have html with an unknown number of elements of a particular class.

For example:

```
The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal 
<span ?class="star-pagination">*112</span> distribution of letters, as 
opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable 
English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use 
Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' 
will uncover <span class="star-pagination">*113</span> many web sites still 
in their infancy.
```

Upon page load, I would like to populate a list such that the user can select a number that corresponds to the instance of .

**End Goal** ultimately I want the list to display the associated page number (e.g. 112 or 113) rather than the instance number (e.g. 1, 2, 3). Finally, an event will redirect the user to the relevant instance (i.e. they will be brought to the "page" they have selected).

I have the following script working to checks the number of elements in class "star-pagination." Right now it just writes a variable to indicate if the file has elements with star pagination.

```
 <script>
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("star-pagination");
 if (x.length < 1)
      window.pagination = "unknown";
 else
     {
         window.pagination = "known";
     }
 <script>
```

Problem 1) Uniquely identifying each element, so that users can be pushed to that element.

One approach I have considered is inserting a unique ID at each element, so that upon clicking an option from the soon to be populated list, an event can be triggered that relies on "document.getElementById('myDiv').scrollIntoView();"

```
 <script>
     var x = document.getElementsByClassName("star-pagination");
     var i;
     for (var i = 0; i< element.length; i++) 
         { 
               x[i].setAttribute("id", i);            
         }
 </script>
```

However, that is definitely not working. I'm bad at javascript and must be doing something wrong in the syntax. Is this a reasonable approach? If so, what is wrong with this syntax? Are there better approaches?

Problem 2) Populating a select list incrementing by 1 for each element in x, starting at the first actual page number (e.g. 112) rather than starting at the instance number (e.g. 1). As best I can tell there are two steps to this: (a) dynamically populating a select form option with units from a list and (b) retrieving the first page number. I imagine there is some regex based solution, but I am not sure how to get that working in javascript. Rather than hacking at that, I figured I would ask if anyone had advice on what the best approach would be?

Comment: can you give a better formatted example? like a raw html version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate the dropdown by appending `option` elements to the `select` element, using the `select` element's `add()` method.

```
var select = document.getElementById("Id_of_my_select_element");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = "option value"; 
option.innerHTML = "option text";
select.add(option);
```

You have a good idea with adding a unique identifier to each of the detected spans, but it's usually a good practice to use a custom property with a `data-` prefix whenever you're adding a property that's just used by your own application. This way you don't have to worry about ID naming collisions that could cause your page HTML to be invalid (that is, if multiple elements on the page somehow end up with the same ID).

```
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i].setAttribute("data-option",i);
}
```

Here's an example of everything working together:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("dropdown");
var pages = document.querySelectorAll(".star-pagination");
// Loop through all matching elements
for (var i = 0, len = pages.length; i < len; i++) {
  // Give the element a custom property by which we can retrieve it
  pages[i].setAttribute("data-option", i);
  // Get the page number from the element
  var text = pages[i].innerHTML;
  var pageNumber = text.slice(1, text.length);
  // Add a corresponding option to the select dropdown
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = i;
  option.innerHTML = pageNumber;
  select.add(option);
}
select.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var targetElement = document.querySelector("[data-option='" + this.value + "']");
  targetElement.scrollIntoView();
});
```

```css
#output {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
  color: darkred;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.star-pagination {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
  <options>
    <option>Please choose a page</option>
  </options>
</select>
<div style="max-height:150px;overflow:scroll;">
  <div id="text">The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
    <span class="star-pagination">*112</span> distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model
    text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover <span class="star-pagination">*113</span> many web sites still in their infancy.</div>
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*115</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*116</span>Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*117</span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*118</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*119</span>Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*120</span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*121</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*122</span>Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*123</span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*124</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*125</span>Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*126</span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*127</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis
  <br/>
  <br/><span class="star-pagination">*128</span>Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you got wrong is that you wrote element.length when you don't have a variable defined with that name.

```
<script>
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("star-pagination");
 var i;
 for (var i = 0; i< x.length; i++)
     { 
           x[i].setAttribute("id", i);            
     }
 </script>
```